# Inkscape crashes after upgrade to Lunar Lobster

Tags: inkscape, 23.04

I have just upgraded from 22.10 to 23.04. This means that I now have [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/) 1.2.2. I am using Inkscape in a script to convert PDFs to PNG and SVG. But, it crashes every time. The following simple use of Inkscape in the terminal triggers the crash: `inkscape -o foo.svg foo.pdf`.

This is the error I see:

> Error: Inkscape encountered an internal error and will close now.
>
> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

What can I do to debug this?

Comment: how about trying the Flatpak version? https://flathub.org/apps/org.inkscape.Inkscape

Comment: It appears to be an active issue on the Inkscape site: https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inkscape/-/issues/4189. You should work directly with their dev team and track (subscribe to) the progress of this issue if it is indeed related.

Comment: @richbl I think that it might be the same issue. I hadn't realised that because in my case the issue isn't obviously anything to do with pdflatex.

Comment: @twsh, please confirm this, and if this is indeed the case, close out this issue (when able). This will help others here in the community who run into the same problem. Thanks

Comment: I think that this is the underlying issue, which is a bug in Inkscape: https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inkscape/-/issues/4177

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is the following known bug in Inkscape: https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inkscape/-/issues/4177